# How to disable Mailchimp double opt-in PHP

Tags: php, forms, api, mailchimp, newsletter

I'm totally new in Mailshimp stuff and I can't find anything on the web to disable the double opt-in.
I don't use any Mailchimp API, I just have the form mailchimp gave me to put in my html.

Any idea without using the API or if I have to, by using the API ?

Thank you !

Comment: http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/disable-final-welcome-email

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   require('Mailchimp.php');
   $api = new Mailchimp( $api_key );

   $result = $api->lists->subscribe( $api_key, $id,  $data['email'], $merge_vars, 'html', false );
```

6th parameter defines that whether to disable the opt-in or not. Pass it as false will disable it.

For more info refer:-http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php

Comment: @KeizerBridge :- Thanks for pointing out. I have edit the code, so that it can be beneficial for others.

Answer (score 1):

Thx Garima but this is for API 1.3.
There is API 2.0 now.

So you can use this snippet https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api

This is the simplest way to use the mailchimp API I think.
Then like you said, you turn to false the double opt_in parameter.

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php

Have A Good Day