# Disable double opt-in in mailchimp by api

Tags: api, mailchimp, newsletter

I am new to mailchip stuff. Does anyone know how to disable double opt-in, by adding any additional parameter:
http://byjakewithlove.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&id=ee0af79b60&c=angular.callbacks._0

Thanks for response in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Mailchimp double opt-in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013592/how-to-disable-mailchimp-double-opt-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable double opt-in using that endpoint. In order to bypass doubl3 opt-in, you'll need to use the MailChimp API

Comment: Thats what I also figured out.